# How do I install pip on ubuntu 14.04 LTS? I got this error while installing

Tags: python, pip

I tried with this command:

```
kv@kv:~$ sudo easy_install pip
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: [Errno 111] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 111] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

Error:

```
The directory '/home/kv/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/kv/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f128ae75a10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f128ae75b90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f128ae75ed0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f128ae75190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f128ae754d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)': /simple/pip/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
```

ERROR2

```
kv@kv:~$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
        working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 446, in _build_master
        return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 459, in _build_from_requirements
        dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
        raise DistributionNotFound(req)
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.0
```

Comment: There is a well-written site that tells you how to [install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Comment: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/

Comment: Maybe you should try `sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried it but I got this long error:
I updated the question with error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include errors or code. Comments don't allow complex formatting.

Comment: @CcL with the command:
'$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip '
I got this error(Updated the qeustion with tag ERROR_2)

Comment: If you can run `sudo pip install`, then you already have pip installed. You can run `pip --version` to see what version you have

Comment: @cricket_007 : I get the same message as the one I have mentioned for ERROR2 in the updated question for 
$pip --version

Comment: I don't see how you would get the same error... `/usr/local/bin/pip` exists, so it is already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection from your host to pypi is failing. This has nothing to do with `python` or `pip` or `easy_install`. What you're trying to do is correct.

You've got to solve your networking issue before you come back to installing things.

For a quicker check, you can just do `curl https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/`. Once you get a list of files in return, try with `easy_install` again.

It could be that the pypi repository was temporarily unavailable as well. If you can access google from that host, just wait a bit before trying again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried the command:
curl https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
followed by this:
$ sudo easy_install pip
and it worked!
Why did the attempt fail the first time?

Comment: In that case, most likely you had a bad luck and tried to install `pip` when the `pypi` service experienced some issues / an outage. If you didn't change anything else, it's unlikely this is related to your system.

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: Downvoted. OP cannot connect to the internet/pypi, his original attempt is not wrong, and this is not a fix.

Comment: Or more specifically, this is not solving the actual problem. I'd definitely recommend installing `python-pip` package instead of using `easy_install` as well, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: The initial post didn't point to connection error, hence the answer.

Answer (score -2):

### Command

sudo apt-get install python-pip

### Output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython-all-dev python-all python-all-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython-all-dev python-all python-all-dev python-pip
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 78 not upgraded.
Need to get 147 kB of archives.
After this operation, 651 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libpython-all-dev amd64 2.7.11-1 [992 B]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python-all amd64 2.7.11-1 [978 B]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python-all-dev amd64 2.7.11-1 [1,000 B]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 python-pip all 8.1.1-2 [144 kB]
Fetched 147 kB in 4s (34.2 kB/s)     
Selecting previously unselected package libpython-all-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 362359 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython-all-dev_2.7.11-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython-all-dev:amd64 (2.7.11-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-all.
Preparing to unpack .../python-all_2.7.11-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-all (2.7.11-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-all-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../python-all-dev_2.7.11-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-all-dev (2.7.11-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pip.
Preparing to unpack .../python-pip_8.1.1-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-pip (8.1.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libpython-all-dev:amd64 (2.7.11-1) ...
Setting up python-all (2.7.11-1) ...
Setting up python-all-dev (2.7.11-1) ...
Setting up python-pip (8.1.1-2) ...
```

Comment: Downvoted. OP cannot connect to the internet/pypi, his original attempt is not wrong, and this is not a fix.